# Seeking Openlayers and GeoServer tutorials?

Tags: geoserver, openlayers, references

Where I can learn to use OpenLayers and GeoServer?

Answer (score -1):

If you want to get some first impressions I'd recommend to have a look on the official

[OL Documentation](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.14.2/doc/). Particularly the quick start section as well as the tutorials should be a good starting point, at least as a first step. You could also have a look on the [examples](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.14.2/examples/).

For geoserver there is also a [quick start](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/googleearth/quickstart.html) section on the official geoserver.org website, as well as on the [OSGeo homepage](http://live.osgeo.org/en/quickstart/geoserver_quickstart.html)
.